# How can I put a space at the end of an inline code block?

Tags: support, markdown, whitespace, inline-code

I'm trying to put "dir " in an inline code section, and ```dir ``` `` doesn't work.  When I do this, the result looks like this: ```dir ` (no space at the end).

How can I put a space at the end of an inline code block?

Comment: I wonder why you would need to?

Comment: So I can say, "type `dir `, then press tab", instead of "type `dir`, then press space, then press tab".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A trailing space in an inline code block is easily missed and will not make your explanation any clearer.

Using the example you stated in the comments above, I would rather say:

> Type `dir` followed by <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>

To back up my statement, consider the following: Type `dir`  followed by <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Did you notice the space after `dir`?  Yes, there is one there, inserted by wrapping the text within `<code>` instead of ``` `` (which inadvertently answers your immediate question).

Comment: I don't notice the space in that `dir`, no, because it's inside a quote  block, and therefore the background is already gray.

Comment: @notfed Removed from quote block. Still not very obvious :)

Comment: Thanks, I agree, I'll have to start using <kbd> more often as well.